# loop through a column of schema.table to return a table (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, loops, dynamic

I have reached the point of limit and think it's time to post the question here.

I have a table stored the `schema_table` info that I want to execute query and loop it to retrieve the values of a common column from. To be specific, this table is as

| schema_table |
| --- |
| class.id |
| class2.grade |
| class.address |

Here, `class` and `class2` are schemas and `id`, `grade` and `address` are tables. All of the three tables have a shared column `name`.

What I would like to obtain is a `name` table, in which names are stored.

I hope to return a name table

| name |
| --- |
| Oliver |
| Maggie |
| Liz. |
| Aaron |

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing this is oversimplifying your problem, right?  `create table name as select name from class.id union select name from class2.grade union select name from class.address`.  I don't want to be one of those people where you say the query has to return 5 and I say "select 5"

Comment: @Hambone, thanks. I would like to select from the attributes of the schema_table column. They are strings. How can I select strings as tables in a query?

Comment: To be specific, I would like to select from each attribute in column `schema_table` in the first table and obtain attributes stored in the `name` column in each of the tables. Here, 'select from each attribute in column schema_table' is weird, I know, as the attributes are not table - I'd like to make that conversion, however.